# how to add Json value into model Array to display into tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm using the tableview to display the Two Json value but the problem is I cant add value into model struct to displaying into tableview using two Api's. i want to show percentage value in one of the cell label and
here is my json

```
[
{
    "Percentage": 99.792098999,
}
]
```

my second json value

```
{
"Categories": [
    "Developer",
    "ios "
],
"Tags": [
    {
        "Value": "kishore",
        "Key": "Name"
    },
    {
        "Value": "2",
        "Key": "office"
    },

]
}
```

and i need show the Categories value in Categories label in tableview

value and key on tableview

here is my Struct

```
struct info: Decodable {

let Categories: String?
let Tags: String?
let Value: String?
let Key: String?
var Name: String?
let percentage: Double?

}
```

here its my code

```
var List = [info]()

do {

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
            print(json as Any)

            guard let jsonArray = json as? [[String: Any]] else {
                return
            }
            print(jsonArray)

            for dic in jsonArray{
                guard let per = dic["percentage"] as? Double else { return }

                print(per)


 }
```

and second json

```
  if let array = json["Tags"] as? [[String: String]] {
                for dict in array {

                    let key = dict["Key"]
                    let value = dict["Value"]
                    switch key {
                    case "office":

                    case "Name":

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

here is my cell for row indexpath

```
 cell.Categories.text  = list[indexpath.row].percentage

    cell.Name.text = list[indexpath.row].name
    cell.office.text = list[indexpath.row].office
```

Comment: where do you fill List array

Comment: im using list.append is getting error

Comment: soo please tell me how to solve this issue

Comment: I can't find the place that you fill List Array , I guess you add two different info Struct instead of modify before struct

Answer (score 0):

Please use Swift 4 Codable protocol to decode the value from JSON.

```
//1.0 Create your structures and make it conform to Codable Protocol
struct Tags: Codable{
    var Key: String
    var Value: String
}

struct Sample: Codable{
    var Categories: [String]
    var Tags: [Tags]
}
```

In your method, perform below steps:

```
//2.0 Get your json data from your API. In example below, i am reading from a JSON file named "Sample.json"
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sample", ofType: "json") {
    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)

        do {
            //3.0 use JSONDecoder's decode method to decode JSON to your model.
            let sample = try JSONDecoder().decode(Sample.self, from: jsonData)

            //4.0 User the "sample" model to do your stuff. Example, printing some values
            print("Sample.Category = \(sample.Categories)")
            print("Sample.Name = \(sample.Tags[0].Value)")
            print("Sample.Office = \(sample.Tags[1].Value)")
        } catch let error {
            print("Error = \(error)")
        }
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: can i use without 2 step you given

Comment: Yes, second step is just an example. You will get jsonData from your api.

Comment: `Codable` is just a `typealias` for `Encodable & Decodable`, he doesn't need to confirm for both .. `Decodable` would do

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `Codable` all the time with JSON even for simpler types so for percentage I would do

```
struct ItemElement: Decodable {
    let percentage: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case percentage = "Percentage"
    }
}
```

and we need to keep these values in a separate array, declared as a class property

```
let percentageList: [Double]()
```

and json encoding would then be

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode([ItemElement].self, from: data)
    percentageList = result.map { item.percentage } 
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Similar for the second part

```
struct Item: Decodable {
    let categories: [String]
    let tags: [Tag]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case categories = "Categories"
        case tags = "Tags"
    }
}

struct Tag: Decodable {
    let value, key: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value = "Value"
        case key = "Key"
    }
}
```

use a dictionary for the result, again as a class property

```
var values = [String: String]()
```

and the decoding

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode(Item.self, from: data)
    for item in result.tags {
        values[item.key] = values.item.value
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

and then in the cell for row code

```
cell.Categories.text  = percentageList[indexpath.row].percentage

cell.Name.text = values["name"]
cell.office.text = values["office"]
```

Note that this last code looks very strange since you don't have an array of name/office values judging by your json. Maybe you have simplified it some way but the code above is the best I can do with the information given even if it possibly wrong